# Correct way to set queryString in react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, react-router-dom

My application uses angularJS, so I'm migrating it to React. I'm navigating to a route: `/index` like this `$urlServiceProvider.rules.otherwise('/index')`.Note that I'm using angularJS's `urlServiceProvider` to navigate to `/index` which has $stateProvider set like this :

```
$stateProvider.state('index', {
     component: AppController,
     url: '/index',
     template: `<div id="application"></div>`
})
```

// AppController.jsx

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import * as React from 'react'
import App from './App'
export class AppController implements ng.IComponentController {
  constructor() {}

  $onInit(): void {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('application'))
  }
}
```

`<App />` component is a component in react which has routes defined for every page.

Now, this works fine but what If I want to set queryString params, which I did it like this: `/index?redirect=true`. Now, inside `<App />` component if I log the value like:

// App

```
const { redirect } = useLocation()
console.log('Redirect value is ', redirect) // Expecting true here
```

I get nothing printed in console. Am I doing it correct here?

Comment: What is `useLocation` hook here? Is it the `useLocation` hook from `react-router-dom`? What version of `react-router-dom` do you have installed?

Comment: Yes, its ```useLocation``` hook from react-router-dom v6

Answer (score 2):

If using `react-router-dom@6` you can use the [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) hook.

Example:

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
const redirect = searchParams.get("redirect");
```

If using `react-router-dom@5` you will need to use the [useLocation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook and access the `location.search` value and instantiate your own [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object.

Example:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { search } = useLocation();
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
const redirect = searchParams.get("redirect");
```

In RRDv5 you can abstract a custom hook to do this for you:

```
const useQuery = () => {
  const { search } = useLocation();
  return React.useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search]);
}
```

Comment: I got the console to print but it's throwing null as the value. This is what I'm passing into urlServiceProvider : ```$urlServiceProvider.rules.otherwise('/index?redirect=true')``` and in $stateProvider : ```$stateProvider.state('index', {
     component: AppController,
     url: '/index',
     template: `<div id="application"></div>`
})```. I don't think I've to do changes in $stateProvider here right?

Comment: @SimmiGeorge I wouldn't *think* you would, but my Angular knowledge is pretty minimal and limited ***really*** old Angular 1 or 2 stuff, and even that I only learned the bare minimum to get stuff to work (*React app built on top of an older Angular app base *).